# What is a good replacement for new Buffer("my string", "binary")

Tags: node.js

According to the node docs the "binary" encoding will be deprecated in future versions.

However I found that my code only works if I create my buffer like this:

```
var buffer = new Buffer("Special chars like ñ and backspace", "binary");
```

What is the right way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: I think the fact that your code doesn't work without that is a sign of deeper problems.

Comment: What are you doing with buffer after that point?

Comment: I'm making an HTTP POST to a server. I can't use the request library so I'm using the standard node HTTP Client object and using its .write function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it simply by passing the encoding parameter to http.write, like this:

```
var http = require("http");
var httpReq = http.request(options, callback);
httpReq.write("some string with special characters", "binary");
```

There are no deprecations in the docs about the write method AFAIK.